# I am working in MySQL Workbench, and am unable to use the UNNEST function; I get an error on the parenthesis

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, unnest

I am new-is to SQL. I am working in MySQL Workbench.
I am trying to use the function UNNEST() to pull data from arrays of strings in a column of the table I am working on, but when I type UNNEST() into the query console, there is a squiggly red line under the first parenthesis with the error:

> "(" is not valid at this position; expecting EOF, ';'

What does this mean? Why can't I use the UNNEST function? I tried using it in the FROM statement and as a CROSS JOIN. No matter where the UNNEST() is, the first parenthesis gets this error.

Comment: The squiggly red line in Workbench indicates that MySQL does not support the `UNNEST()` function. Here's the reference for MySQL builtin functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-function-reference.html

Comment: https://www.sql-workbench.eu/dbms_comparison.html shows that `UNNEST()` is supported by PostgreSQL, IBM DB2, and HSQLDB. It may also be supported by some other brands of SQL database not shown in that table, but not MySQL.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!